# How do I make a command block teleport 2 specific people but only when they are in range?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to set a command that only teleports 2 specific players when they are in a certain radius. It should teleport the players Supernova186 and Creeperface1016 to 323 5 81 but, only when they are 10 blocks near it. Every attempt I do it says please specify the player, and when I do it does nothing. Version 1.11.12

Comment: Good idea to also give what commands you are using that aren't working.

Answer (score -1):

With my known knowledge, if you have 2 command blocks connected with a repeater it should work with these commands:

1st Command: `/tp Supernova186[r=10] 323 5 81`

2nd Command: `/tp Creeperface1016[r=10] 323 5 81`

**NOTE: It also depends where you put the command block. It would be better to put them next to each other using a repeater. Thus next to each other, one of the command blocks would be set to a radius of 10 while the other is set to 12 since it's 2 blocks away.**

Comment: Or just place them on top of each other?